# Convert string representation of list to list when elements are not encased in quotes

Tags: python, string, list

Similar to [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list) but consider the elements in the list are not encased in quotes, e.g

```
x = '[a, b, c, ab, adc, defg]'
```

How could you convert this to a list of string elements in python?

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'adc', 'defg']
```

Comment: Where did you get `x` from? Why is it in that format to begin with?

Comment: Its from a SQL query where the underlying data structure is `array<string>`

Comment: Can whatever library you're using to access the DB not parse that for you?

Comment: It's via athena, thanks for the suggestion, certainly worth exploring this route but I don't know how yet.

Comment: I think it is worth it, because otherwise you could get into all sorts of problems when your elements also contain characters like `,`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it's a string, you can take the square brackets off and split by your delimiter:

```
>>> x = '[a, b, c, ab, adc, defg]'
>>> x[1:-1].split(', ')

['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'adc', 'defg']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
>>> x = '[a, b, c, ab, adc, defg]'
>>> [i.strip(',[]') for i in x.split()]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'adc', 'defg']
```

But of course, this assumes this exact format and nothing else more complicated

Answer (score 0):

Below

```
x = '[a, b, c, ab, adc, defg]'
l = x[x.find('[') + 1: x.find(']')].split(',')
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do following:

```
import re
x = '[a, b, c, ab, adc, defg]'
x = re.sub(r"[\[\]]", "", x)
split_x = x.split(',')
print(split_x)
```